# Setting start and end dates by quarter given a date range

Tags: excel, vba

I need help coding this one as a function in Excel-VBA. I honestly don't think if I will be able to explain this clearly but here goes.

I have a date range which can be any date within the same year

Sample date range:
Date A = 01/15/2019
Date B = 12/10/2019

I have to split the dates into start and end dates for each Quarter of the year it covers. Since the DateA is in Q1, the 1st start date will be the given DateA and the 1st end date will be the end of the Q1(March 31). So for this example:

start date 1 = 01/15/2019
end date 1 = 03/31/2019

Moving forward, I now have to get the dates starting from Q2 to DateB.

This is what I have started with so far. First, I have to find which quarter the range starts.

```
Select Case Month(startdate)
    Case 1 to 3
       'what to do
    Case 3 to 6
       'what to do
    Case 7 to 9
        'what to do
    Case 10 to 12
        'what to do
End Select
```

I don't know yet how to code the next steps or how to proceed coding from here.

The final result must be as follows:

> start date 1 = 01/15/2019
>  end date 1 = 03/31/2019
>
> start date 2 = 04/01/2019
>  end date 2 = 06/30/2019
>
> start date 3 = 07/01/2019
>  end date 3 = 09/30/2019
>
> start date 4 = 10/01/2019
>  end date 4 = 12/10/2019

Comment: I assume end date 4 is a type-o and it should be 12/31/2019?

Comment: Hi! Nope. The the expected end date still should be DateB from the given date range even if it ends in the 4th quarter. The date covered should only be from DateA to DateB. For example, DateB can be 08/01/2019(Q3). between DateA to Date B, it covers only 3 Quarters. Therefore, the results will just be Q1-Q3:

start date 1 = 01/15/2019
...
...
start date 3 = 07/01/2019
end date 3 = 08/01/2019 
----nothing follows----

Comment: Oh I see. Hmm okay, I'll modify my answer. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Can you include a couple more examples? What would you do if it was Q1 and start date was April 4? Or what about if the start date was a previous year?

Comment: By "if it was Q1" are you refering to the dateB? If DateA is in Q1 and DateB is also Q1, then it will only return one pair of dates. 

example 1:
A = 01/15/2019 \\Q1
B = 02/21/2019 \\Q1

startdate 1 = A
end date 1 = B

-------------------

example 2
A = 07/20/2019 \\Q3
B = 10/06/2019 \\Q4

startdate 1 = 07/20/2019
end date 1 = 10/06/2019

Comment: example 3
A = 04/04/2019 \\Q2
B = 10/06/2019 \\Q4

startdate 1 =  04/04/2019
end date 1 = 06/30/2019
start date 2 = 07/01/2019
end date 2 = 09/30/2019
start date 3 = 10/01/2019
end date 3 = 10/06/2019

**notice that startdate1 is always A and enddate(num of quarters covered) is also B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two custom functions should do it. I assume that someone wouldn't have any situations where a start date was later than the quarter. You could update the formula to capture one variable such as March 31,2018, but I just set it to grab the quarter number and year.

```
Function startDate(beginTIME As Date, QuarterNumber As Long, TheYEar As Long) As Date
    Dim Q_BeginDates(1 To 4) As Date

    Q_BeginDates(1) = DateSerial(TheYEar, 1, 1)
    Q_BeginDates(2) = DateSerial(TheYEar, 4, 1)
    Q_BeginDates(3) = DateSerial(TheYEar, 7, 1)
    Q_BeginDates(4) = DateSerial(TheYEar, 10, 1)

    If beginTIME < Q_BeginDates(QuarterNumber) Then
        startDate = Q_BeginDates(QuarterNumber)
    Else
        startDate = beginTIME
    End If



End Function


Function endDate(endTIME As Date, QuarterNumber As Long, TheYEar As Long) As Date
    Dim Q_EndDates(1 To 4) As Date

    Q_EndDates(1) = DateSerial(TheYEar, 3, 31)
    Q_EndDates(2) = DateSerial(TheYEar, 6, 30)
    Q_EndDates(3) = DateSerial(TheYEar, 9, 30)
    Q_EndDates(4) = DateSerial(TheYEar, 12, 31)

    If endTIME > Q_EndDates(QuarterNumber) Then
        endDate = Q_EndDates(QuarterNumber)
    Else
        endDate = endTIME
    End If

End Function
```

Also, I still would recommend non-VBA. Here's a method I did on a mockup...

The formula in cell C5 is `=IF(A1<DATE(LEFT(B5,4),CHOOSE(RIGHT(B5,1),1,4,7,10),1),DATE(LEFT(B5,4),CHOOSE(RIGHT(B5,1),1,4,7,10),1),$A$1)`

The formula in cell D5 is:
`=IF($B$1>DATE(LEFT(B5,4),CHOOSE(RIGHT(B5,1),3,6,9,12),CHOOSE(RIGHT(B5,1),31,30,30,31)),DATE(LEFT(B5,4),CHOOSE(RIGHT(B5,1),3,6,9,12),CHOOSE(RIGHT(B5,1),31,30,30,31)),$B$1)`

[image]

Comment: I'll try it try it out! The project requires VBA because I will be running Macro to process the dates but I'm fairly new to macro and vba so this helps a lot. Thank you very much! Happy weekend :)